# Cannot export customer list in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, csv, export

I was trying to export a customer list to a CSV file in Magento 2 (2.2.7). 
[image]

But every time I try it comes up with a 500 error regardless of how many customers are included in the export.

[image]

Exporting sales works fine so it's not an error with exporting generally.
I've checked the developer console and it comes up with a js error.

[image]

Looking in the logs I also found the following error message:

> GET
>   /myadmin/mui/export/gridToCsv/key/a07f4aed6c1179773233c13c4e984264d2309de49d34d35fe8580a8c42ca54cb/?filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&filters%5Bcreated_at%5D%5Bfrom%5D=02%2F01%2F2019&filters%5Bcreated_at%5D%5Bto%5D=02%2F07%2F2019&search=&namespace=customer_listing&selected=false
>   HTTP/1.0

I'm not very experienced with Magento so I'm not sure what is causing this error. I'd appreciate some help to resolve this situation please.

Comment: Have you created any custom attribute?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I have the Open Source edition and it doesn't give the option to create customer attributes. We did migrate from Magento 1 recently though, not sure if that has anything to do with it but thought I'd better mention it.

Comment: You can check your error in `var\log\`

Comment: Hi. Would that be the exception.log or system.log because it doesn't seem to be showing up in either of those.

Comment: Remove `var` & `generated` folder 
then again export data and check in bot log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some custom extension in your magento that has created custom customer attribute through setup script of that module and included column in customer_listing.xml file.

For example i had a module which has added a column mobile number in customer_listing.xml which caused this issue for me.

Kindly check.

If not sure, then try to disable all custom extension and check.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into that. Where would I find the customer_grid.xml file?

Comment: In your custom module it should be located at view/adminhtml/ui_component. The name of the file is 'customer_listing.xml', not 'customer_grid.xml', it was my type mistake.

Comment: Have removed a corrupt extension and reset file permissions so seems that this was the answer. Thank you.